# send email alert to opportunity owner when opportunities closed date has passed

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I want to send email alerts to opportunity owners when their opportunity close date passed. Let say if an opportunity owner have 4 opportunities with same close date so only one email alert should trigger with all 4 opportunity details like Opportunity name, close date and Salesforce link.
I know it can be achieve by batch apex but my batch is not working. I haven't get any error. schedule job done is showing in Schedule job view.
but Opportunity owner didn't get any email.
Please find below my batch:

```
global class SendEmailToopsowner implements Database.Batchable<sObject>  {
map<string,list<opportunity>> userEmailTasklistmap = new map<string,list<opportunity>>();

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Name, StageName, CloseDate, Owner.Email FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate < TODAY  and StageName != 'closed-Won' or StageName != 'closed-Lost'  ]);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<opportunity> scope){
    for(opportunity opp : scope){
        if(!userEmailTasklistmap.Containskey(opp.owner.email)){
            userEmailTasklistmap.put(opp.owner.email, new list<opportunity>());
        }
        userEmailTasklistmap.get(opp.owner.email).add(opp);

      }  
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        for(string email : userEmailTasklistmap.keyset()){

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            list<string> toAddresses = new list<string>();
            toAddresses.add(email);
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            mail.setSubject('Opportunity close date passed');                
            String username = userEmailTasklistmap.get(email)[0].owner.name;
            String htmlBody = '';

            htmlBody = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8" align="center" bgcolor="#F7F7F7">'+
                        +'<tr>'+
                          +'<td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; font-family:Calibri;line-height: 18px; color: #333;"><br />'+
                               +'<br />'+
                                +'Dear '+username+',</td>'+
                        +'</tr>'+
                        +'<tr>'+
                            +'<td style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; font-family:Calibri; line-height: 18px; color: #333;"> You have Pending Task </td>'+
                        +'</tr>'+
                    +'</table>';

            htmlBody +=  '<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse"><tr><th>Name</th><th>StageName</th><th>CloseDate</th></tr>';
            for(opportunity opp : userEmailTasklistmap.get(email)){

                String CloseDate = '';
                if (opp.CloseDate != null)
                    CloseDate = opp.CloseDate.format();                    
                else
                    CloseDate = '';
                String Name = opp.Name;
                datetime dt = opp.CloseDate;
                string ClosedDate = dt.format('M/d/yyyy');
                string StageName = opp.StageName;
                string View = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+ opp.id;
                string clickhere = view;                    
                htmlBody += '<tr><td>' + Clickhere +'</td><td>' + Name + '</td><td>' + CloseDate + '</td><td>' + CloseDate + '</td></tr>';                    
            }
             htmlBody += '</table><br>';
             mail.sethtmlBody(htmlBody);
             mails.add(mail);                    
        }
         if(mails.size()>0)
         Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){        
}
}
```

Kindly help!

Comment: did u try executing the batch from your dev console and checking the debug logs to see whats going on ?

Comment: I am getting error message: Line: 1, Column: 14
Global type must be contained inside of a global class

Comment: try declaring your map `SendEmailToopsowner` as Global.

Comment: Like this                                                                                                           global class SendEmailToopsowner implements Database.Batchable<sObject>  {
Global map<string,list<opportunity>> userEmailTasklistmap = new map<string,list<opportunity>>(); @crmprogdev

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd try. I'd hope you'd be creating a test class for this batch class which would allow you to quickly test and resolve the issues you're encountering.

Comment: (1) `map<string,list<opportunity>> userEmailTasklistmap = new map<string,list<opportunity>>();` should be declared inside `execute()` as it is only used there. (2)N.B. unless this is managed package; you can use `public` as access modifiers throughout

Comment: @cropredy That makes much more sense to me now that I see what you've written! Line 1 code errors rarely are at line 1. But when they give a column number... ...it was just too early in the morning for me to think that clearly to see that here. LOL! Good catch!

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev. Issue is resolved. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Russelbaker1 Making it Global did it for you? If so, I'd highly recommend following cropredy's solution to move that declaration into the `Execute` method and making it `public` instead. In any case, glad to hear we got you sorted.